# When running boxplor or anova: Error in boxplot.default(split(mf[[response]], mf[-response])

Tags: r, anova

I have a file that I formatted for ANOVA but for I cannot run the function boxplot nor aov on it.  [It can be downloaded from this link:](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7hcznd4DKKQSkxRNi0tVUxpdE0/view?usp=sharing)
When running `"boxplot(AnovaPolyg.boxplot(AnovaPolyg...Sheet1$Frequency~AnovaPolyg...Sheet1$Race)..Sheet1$Frequency~AnovaPolyg...Sheet1$Race)`
or

```
anov.aov=aov(AnovaPolyg...Sheet1$Race~AnovaPolyg...Sheet1$Frequency)
```

I get the following error:

Error in boxplot.default(split(mf[[response]], mf[-response]), ...) : 
  adding class "factor" to an invalid object

Can someone please check the data file and tell me if they spot the problem?

Comment: I don't follow your examples, but I think the issue could be when you read in the data, it is treating `Frequency` as a factor. This is because on line 25838, the entry is 0,1 instead of 0.1. FIx this, read the data back in, check to make sure it's numeric (`str` will help with this), and you should be good to go.

Comment: Nice. Glad it was simple. I'll add it as an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't follow your examples, but I think the issue could be when you read in the data, it is treating `Frequency` as a factor. This is because on line 25838, the entry is `0,1` instead of `0.1`. Fix this, read the data back in, check to make sure it's numeric (`str` will help with this), and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I just the same error when i tried to do boxplot between two binary variables. Instead when tried for boxplot between one binary and one scale variable, error is gone. Just my thoughts.